# LaTeX: utf8 and \phantom

Tags: listingsutf8

I'm sorry if this is already answered, but I'm way out of my league.
I'm using a custom style package and it uses \phantom to keep stuff(like the toc) of the title page, but for other reasons I need to use

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

and the template used

```
\usepackage[newansi]{inputenc}
```

and now the \phantom doesn't work. What can I do? 
In theory I just need to keep the front page clear (besides the style stuff), besides that it works fine.

From the .sty....

```
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(79,670){\footnotesize{\AFLEVERINGSDATO}}}%
\phantom{Usynlig, men nødvendig}
\vspace*{5cm}
```

Error:

```
./Bachelorprojekt.tex:110: Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined []
```

That disappears if the \phantom is removed, so I guess that's the problem.

The whole .sty has not been included - I can't get it to show like code and it's 133 lines,

Comment: It is not related to the \phantom command but to the characters inside. You need to make sure that your files are saved in the encoding that you specify. (utf-8 if you have a choice as that is the future, the 8bit encodings such as latin9 are really a legacy and ansinew was never a standard encoding at all) But you can use any encoding you like so long as you use the one you say you are using.

Comment: Since phantom chars will not show anyway, you can replace your ø by a "o" (I guess they have roughly the same width).

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
{\inputencoding{ansinew}\phantom{Usynlig, men nødvendig}}
```